# Dotfuscator renaming File version and product version as blank

Tags: c#, dotfuscator

Dotfuscator tool renaming "file version" and "product version" as blank after obfuscation.

Can we exclude these attributes from renaming?

The tool being used - [https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/[dotfuscator][1]](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/%5Bdotfuscator%5D%5B1%5D)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, so I reached out to support and they told me to add these lines in the properties section:

```
<propertylist>
        <property name="ILDASM_v4.0" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\ildasm.exe"/>
        <property name="ILASM_v4.0" value="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ilasm.exe"/>
</propertylist>
```

That was the solution in my particular case - hope it helps you.